# Lambda go1.x Deprecation Deployment

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, aws-lambda

With the change to AWS Lambda no longer supporting the go1.x runtime, has any successfully deployed a go application to lambda?  I have followed the instructions I believe correctly at the following link.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/migrating-aws-lambda-functions-from-the-go1-x-runtime-to-the-custom-runtime-on-amazon-linux-2/

No matter what I do I always receive the following error.

```
{
  "errorType": "Runtime.InvalidEntrypoint",
  "errorMessage": "RequestId: f703fab9-c945-43f8-858a-d1e87f11f1cf Error: fork/exec /main: exec format error"
}
```

Test lambda function
main.go

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/lambda"
)

type MyEvent struct {
    Name string `json:"name"`
}

func HandleRequest(ctx context.Context, event *MyEvent) (*string, error) {
    if event == nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("received nil event")
    }
    message := fmt.Sprintf("Hello %s!", event.Name)
    return &message, nil
}

func main() {
    lambda.Start(HandleRequest)
}
```

Following the zip instructions here is my build routine:

```
 GOARCH=amd64 GOOS=linux CGO_ENABLED=0 go build -tags lambda.norpc -o bootstrap cmd/test/main.go
 zip test.zip bootstrap
```

Lambda Configuration:

```
  handler       = "bootstrap"
  runtime       = "provided.al2"
  architectures = ["arm64"]
```

I have also tried going with the docker approach listed on the migration instructions as well with the following file.

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/provided:al2 as build
# install compiler
RUN yum install -y golang
RUN go env -w GOPROXY=direct
# cache dependencies
ADD go.mod go.sum ./
RUN go mod download
# build
ADD . .
RUN go build -tags lambda.norpc -o /main cmd/test/main.go
# copy artifacts to a clean image
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/provided:al2
COPY --from=build /main /main
ENTRYPOINT [ "/main" ]
```

Note: The only thing different here from the example is pointing to the specific main.go file to build.

Comment: "While the go1.x runtime allows you to use any executable name, the provided.al2 runtime requires you to use bootstrap as the executable name". You're building as `main` and **must** use `bootstrap`.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I build on an Intel Mac and the architect provided in the AWS docs does not work on my machine.  The correct build command is the following.

```
GOARCH=arm64 GOOS=linux CGO_ENABLED=0 go build -tags lambda.norpc -o bootstrap cmd/test/main.go
```

This now runs correctly in lambda when uploading as a zip.